# Why does calling a function in jQuery need to be wrapped in a method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

Let's say I have a function:

```
function myFunction() {
 ...
}
```

I want to call it from event handler. Why this construction doesn't call my function?

```
$(window).resize(myFunction());
```

But this does the trick:

```
$(window).resize(function(){myFunction()});
```

What is the difference between these types of calling?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
$(window).resize(myFunction());
```

immediately **calls** `myFunction` and passes the **return value** to `resize`. Adding parenthesis after a function name/reference calls the function.

On the other hand,

```
$(window).resize(function(){myFunction()});
```

passes an *anonymous function* to `resize`. `myFunction` is only called when the outer function is called.

Anonymous functions are nothing special. In this case it is just some kind of *inline function definition*. You can easily replace it with a function reference:

```
var handler = function(){myFunction()}; // take out the function definition
$(window).resize(handler);  // and replace it with the new name
```

Now you can see that there are no parenthesis after the function name, which means, `handler` is not called, only the reference is passed.

I hope you can also see now that creating a new function in this example is not necessary. You can achieve the same by simply passing a reference to `myFunction`:

```
$(window).resize(myFunction);
```

---

But both ways have their use cases.

The first example `$(window).resize(myFunction());` can still be useful if `myFunction` **returns a function** that should be used as event handler:

```
function myFunction() {
    var handler = function() {};
    return handler;
}
```

Maybe the handler retuned depends on a parameter passed to `myFunction`.

Passing an anonymous function is necessary if you want to call `myFunction` with some specific arguments:

```
function myFunction(a, b) {
    alert(a + b);
}

$(window).resize(function(){
    myFunction(40, 2);
});
```

---

**Update:**

[@T.J. Crowder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157247/t-j-crowder) made an important comment about the [`event` object](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/). Every event handler gets the event object passed as first parameter. If you'd define your function as

```
function myFunction(event) {
 ...
}
```

to have (easier) access to it, using an anonymous function, you would have to pass it through:

```
$(window).resize(function(event){myFunction(event)});
```

if you want to use it.

Comment: *"You can achieve the same by only passing a reference to `myFunction`:"* It's *slightly* different. In that case, `myFunction` will receive the `event` argument, whereas with his/her `$(window).resize(function(){myFunction()});` version, `myFunction` doesn't see the `event` argument.