# Using a function

Tags: jquery, function, resize, window

Hey wasn't sure how to explain or ask this question so I'll demonstrate with code, say I have this:

```
$(function() {

    $(window).resize(foo());

    function foo() {
        alert('bar');
    }

});
```

How do I make that work instead of doing this:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    foo();
});
```

Comment: Tried it on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/medopal/tfBsu/ and the first one does actually work!

Comment: Can you show me how you would like to call it? Then I can show you how to write it

Comment: This question seems like a repost of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6483383/call-a-function. As @zzzz pointed out, you need to reference the function name without including parentheses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(function() {

  $(window).resize(foo);


});


function foo() {
    alert('bar');
}
```

You basically need to pass the function pointer to jquery.. when you do `function(){foo();}` you are creating an anonymous function.

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/anilkamath87/6WBKv/)

Comment: My bad, I did actually test this prior to posting the question only to find out it hasn't been working due to an error in my js elsewhere.

Comment: Good and simple explanation, just one thing - the `$(window).resize(foo);` can be located outside `$(document).ready` event (or its shortcut) as the `window` always exists, don't need to wait until it exists.

Comment: well I thought abt that.. but the function might be processing something in the dom right and if the user resizes the window when the dom is loading then you might see sm issues..